# noi4r gem install issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

In trying to install the nio4r gem. I tried

```
gem install nio4r -v '1.0.0'
```

The error that pops up is:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nio4r:

ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150406-11564-1qtifmf.rb extconf.rb

checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for sys/select.h... yes
checking for poll.h... yes
checking for sys/epoll.h... no
checking for sys/event.h... yes
checking for sys/queue.h... yes
checking for port.h... no
checking for sys/resource.h... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling monitor.c
In file included from monitor.c:6:
In file included from ./nio4r.h:10:
/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/backward/rubyio.h:2:2: warning: use "ruby/io.h" instead of "rubyio.h" [-W#warnings]
warning use "ruby/io.h" instead of "rubyio.h"

...
```

What am I getting wrong? Is it an issue with my RVM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some basic updates, I was able to get it to work.

`bundle update`

and then

`bundle`

installs the gem.

Thanks to https://github.com/celluloid/nio4r/issues/46

Another approach would be to install a later version of ruby with RVM and do `bundle` again. Both works

Comment: I had to run `bundle update nio4r` and add to the list all other gems that were failing too, and it worked great.